# TypeScript compiler errors in node modules, but not in library source code

Tags: typescript

I have the following code in the library I have written where `canDeleteResult` is of type `CanDeleteProfileResponse`

```js
export type CanDeleteProfileResponse =
    | {
          canDelete: true;
      }
    | {
          canDelete: false;
          resolutionSteps: DeleteProfileResolutionStep[];
          cause: Error;
      };
```

This is my library code that compiles without errors:

```js
    const deleteProfile = async (id: string) => {
        const canDeleteResult = await userDataClient.canDeleteProfile(id, {
            profiles: profiles ?? [],
        });

        if (!canDeleteResult.canDelete && canDeleteResult.resolutionSteps.length) {
            await tryToResolveDeletion(canDeleteResult.resolutionSteps);
        } else if (!canDeleteResult.canDelete) {
            throw canDeleteResult.cause;
        }

        await userDataClient.deleteProfile(id);
    };
```

When I hover over the code with my mouse, canDeleteResult is not explicitly of type `CanDeleteProfileResponse`.

[image]

But when I consume this package and it is in node modules of another project, TypeScript throws as error because of the union in type `const canDeleteResult: CanDeleteProfileResponse`

[image]

The error:

[image]

Why is TypeScript throwing an error when the library is consumed, but not in its source code?

Comment: What TypeScript versions do you have in each project?

Comment: TypeScript version 4.3.5